# VBA login and logout Facebook

Tags: facebook, vba

I am using the following code to login on Facebook with VBA.

```
Sub LoginFb()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")
    IE.Navigate ("www.Facebook.com")
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = "username"
    IE.Document.all.Item("pass").Value = "password!"
    IE.Document.all.Item("persist_box").status = False
    IE.Document.all.Item("loginbutton").Click
End Sub
```

Also, I want to implement logout from Facebook in VBA.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I implement logout from Facebook in VBA?

Comment: Well you're clicking the `loginbutton` to log in, how about clicking the `logoutbutton` to log out?

Comment: The above code is a part of an automation. For this reason, I want not to remain connected because when the code runs again finds it logged in and is appearing an error in VBA code.

Comment: Well you're not handling any errors.. put `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` at the top of the procedure, add an `ErrHandler:` label at the end of it. Verify an element is effectively in the DOM before you access its `.Value`, too. Then consider using an actual Facebook API instead of fiddling with a DOM in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are login into Facebook with the persist box unchecked with the following line:
`IE.Document.all.Item("persist_box").status = False`
I think that you can log out by simply closing the Internet Explorer window with the following command: `IE.Quit`
Then if you need to continue your automation process with other username/password you can login again with the same IE object.